# My App Crashes and produce the 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios4, core-data, ios5, xcode4.2

my app crashes after execution of the following line of code:-

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewControllerObj animated:YES];
```

and it gives the following error message at the console window:--

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key detailDescriptionLabel.'

i spend a lot of time to find solution but not succeed..
Please help me in finding solution..

Comment: It seems that detailViewControllerObj is nil. Have you instantiated it before call?

Comment: thanx flink for ur reply ..i catch the silly error in what i did...

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem ….the problem is that i am coding on Xcode 4.2 which automatically generates the two view control files root view and detailViewController files and my habit of adding controls by coding leaves me low concentration on detailViewController xib file after deleting the existing code in DetailViewCntroller  .h and .m files i forgot to delete a detailViewLabel from the DetailViewController xib file..…..